# Simple Utterance after Launch request Amazon Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I just got into Alexa and made the classic "Space fact" skill. However, I didn´t find any resources on how to add utterances after the launch request.

An example of what I want to do:
Me: Alexa open Space Facts
Alexa: Saturn is big
Me: next

I thought the command "next" has to be an utterance. I thought about using slots or intent confirmation, but I don't think that will work as well, will it?

What I want to achieve is that after one space fact, a user can simply say "next" or "one more" to trigger my function again.

Did I just miss something, is it not documented or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Space Fact skill has an array of facts. So all you have to do is to pick one from the array when the user says "Next" or "One more".

**Use AMAZON.NextIntent**
In order to capture the user's *"Next"* utterance, use the predefined `AMAZON.NextIntent` in your interaction model. So when the users say *"Next"* this intent will be mapped. Also add *"one more"* as an extra utterance for this intent.

Now, in your backend code add `AMAZON.NextIntent` handler and for its response get another fact from the fact array. (Add some logic so that the skill wont randomly return the same fact again. You can use `sessionAttributes` to keep track of read fact indexes)

**Note:** In order for Alexa to wait for users input after it says the first fact, you need to keep the session alive. As far as I remember the fact skill ends the session after it says the first fact.

The session is kept alive based on `shouldEndSession` parameter in the response. For any request, if not provided, `shouldEndSession` defaults to `true`. In your case, the response to `LaunchRequest` should have this `shouldEndSession` parameter set to `false`. Only by which the session remains open and users can say *"next"*.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51959848/1574023) to know more about how you can keep the session alive using ask-nodejs-sdk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn´t know there is a predefined "NextIntent", thats probably why I had troubles. Awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add your conversation (Utterances and responses) in the ASK developer console only under the build tab. 
You will need to do the following - 
1. Create intent
2. Add utterances
3. Add response
4. Save and build